# Как написать обработчик события для попадания товара "в список покупок" на сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-метрика

В карточке товара есть кнопка "В список покупок".
При клике на нее товар падает в сам список покупок. Повторно товар не может туда попасть, пока не удален из этого списка.
Мне нужно поставить цель для яндекс метрики, которая отслеживает добавление товара в список покупок. Как это сделать? Не могу понять какое имя события здесь вообще использовать. Возможно ли это сделать без взаимодействия с сервером?

Comment: Вы это читали? https://yandex.ru/support/metrica/simple-goal/click.html#form-simple-goal

Comment: Если у тебя есть вопросы по поводу каких-то распространенных технологий, и вопрос типа а есть ли такое или как это то можешь юзать гпт а потом от того что он выдал отталкиватся. Он даст тебе хотябы представление что да как

Comment: @DaemonHK и что мне это даст? Пользователи могут сколько угодно жать на кнопку. Мне нужно чтобы цель срабатывала тогда, когда в списке нет товара , надо это учитывать. Или я что то не до конца понимаю ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#add-to-cart-button').click(function() {
  var listItem = $('#item-id'); // Замените 'item-id' на идентификатор товара
  var isItemInCart = listItemInCart(listItem);

  if (!isItemInCart) {
    // Отправка события в Яндекс.Метрику
    ym('your_metrika_id', 'reachGoal', 'add_to_cart');

    // Дополнительные действия, если требуется
    // Например, изменение внешнего вида кнопки или другие манипуляции с элементами страницы
  }
});

function listItemInCart(listItem) {
  // Проверка наличия товара в списке покупок
  // Вернуть true, если товар уже есть в списке, иначе вернуть false
  // Например, можно проверить наличие соответствующего класса или атрибута у элемента списка
  return listItem.hasClass('in-cart');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это же просто цель для клика на кнопку.
Мне нужно чтобы цель срабатывала в том случае, если в списке нету товара. А если он есть, то цель не должна срабатывать.

Comment: Изменил. Попробуй

Comment: _В приведенном коде 12345678 - это идентификатор вашего счетчика Яндекс.Метрики._ - где?

Comment: Я код поменял а текст нет

Comment: так поправьте тогда

Comment: Ну как-то так. Оно стремно но должно работать